# Complex arrays in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I'm trying to make an array in javascript, but its a little complex and i need your help.
    I want to set each image in "items" in a div in "`contentid`", each item in items have 2 or 3 image, so this images should set in a div, for example:
    "`[{ image: '../Images/1-1.PNG ' },{ image: '../Images/1-2.PNG' }]`" these are first item in items and these image should set in dvHomerow1 and...
    these are my codes in js and html, and would appreciate it if anybody can help me:

```
//javascript
 $("document").ready(function () {
    var x = 500 
    var Title = [{ title: "Metro UI template" },
                 { title: "Build Windows 8 style websites, with ease" }]
    $("#dvTitle").append("<div class='col-lg-8'><a href = '#'><h1>" +
        Title[0].title + "</h1><h4>" + Title[1].title + "</h4></div> ");
    var Menu = [
       { title: "Home", image: '../Icons/1.png' },
       { title: "Download",image: '../Icons/2.png' },
       { title: "Support", image: '../Icons/3.png' }
    ]
    for (i = 0; i < Menu.length; i++) {
        $("#dvTitleMenu").append("<div class='col-lg-2'><a href='#'> <h4 > " + Menu[i].title +
        "</h4><img src=" + Menu[i].image + "  style='width:30px; height:30px;'/> </a></div> ");
    }
    var x = 250;
    var y = 130;
    var aMenu = [
       {           
           title: "Home",
           contentid: ["dvHomerow1","dvHomerow2","dvHomerow3"],
           items: [[{ image: '../Images/1-1.PNG ' },
                   { image: '../Images/1-2.PNG' }],
                   [{ image: '../Images/1-3.PNG' },
                   { image: '../Images/1-4.PNG' }],
                   [{ image: '../Images/1-5.PNG' }]],

       },
       {     
           title: "Download",
           contentid: ["dvDownloadrow1", "dvDownloadrow2"],
           items: [[{ image: '../Images/2-1.PNG' }],
                   [{ image: '../Images/2-2.PNG' },
                   { image: '../Images/2-3.PNG' },
                   { image: '../Images/2-4.PNG' }]],

       },
      {     
          title: "Support",
          contentid: ["dvSupportrow1", "dvSupportrow2"],
          items: [[{ image: '../Images/3-1.PNG' }],
                 [{ image: '../Images/3-2.PNG' },
                 { image: '../Images/3-3.PNG' },
                 { image: '../Images/3-4.PNG' }]],

      }
    ]
    for (i = 0; i < aMenu.length; i++) {
        $("#" + aMenu[i].contentid).append("<a href='#'><h3>" + aMenu[i].title + "</h3></a>");
        for (var k = 0; k < aMenu[i].contentid.length;k++){
        for (var j = 0; j < aMenu[i].items.length; j++) {
            var app = "<a href='#'><img src='" + aMenu[i].items[j].image + "'";
            app += " style='width:" + aMenu[i].items[j].w + "height:" + aMenu[i].items[j].h + "'class= ' max-width:100%;' </a> ";
            $("#" + aMenu[i].contentid[k]).append(app);
        }
        }
    }
});
..................................................
//HTML
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link href="../Site/StyleSheet.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="../Scripts/JavaScript.js"></script>

</head>
<body id="body">

            <nav class="nav" >
                <div id="dvHeader" class="row">
                    <div id="dvTitle" class="col-md-7">
                    </div>
                    <div id="dvTitleMenu" class="col-md-5 col-md-push-1">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </nav>


            <div id="container">
                <div  class="col-md-3">
                    <div id="dvHome" class="row col-md-12">
                        <div id="dvHomerow1">

                        </div>
                        <div id="dvHomerow2">

                        </div>
                        <div id="dvHomerow3">

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3 ">
                    <div id="dvDownload" class="col-md-12 row">
                        <div id="dvDownloadrow1">

                        </div>
                        <div id="dvDownloadrow2">

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3 ">
                    <div id="dvSupport" class="col-md-12 row">
                        <div id="dvSupportrow1">

                        </div>
                        <div id="dvSupportrow2">

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your error is here: `aMenu[i].items[j].image`

Infact:

- `aMenu` is an array (and you can use the `i` index)
- `aMenu.items` is a matrix (array of array) so you can't use a single `j` index

A solution is to loop over elements contained in every `items[j]` array.

By the way, in my mind, you should design better your data structure... to avoid this kind of problems... :)